# Cannot use echo command if i import except in script

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I want to use expect method in my script so i used this command in script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
```

now I'm unable to declare any array or even use echo commands after using this command

Full Code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
declare -a arr=("ip1" "ip2")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do

   spawn ssh myhost@i
   send "exit\n"
done
```

The entire array declaration and for loop throws error like **invalid command name** , i'm not able to use echo command . when i try the echo command without importing except everything works as expected .

Comment: You aren't importing anything. `except` is a completely different program from `bash`, and you are using that (not `bash`) to execute the script.

Comment: `except` is virtually never the right way to automate an `ssh` connection like this. Set up public-key authorization instead.

Comment: can you please tell me what needs to be done to use the array declaration and echo commands ?

Comment: i'm able to use echo commands and array declaration if i don't use expect command in program . but if i use this #!/usr/bin/expect . i'm not able to .

Comment: Yes, because `expect` and `bash` are two completely different programs. You are trying to execute a shell script with `expect`; you can't do that. You need to write a script in `expect`.

Comment: Expect uses the [tag:tcl] language. try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more comfortable with shell scripts.

Answer (score 3):

The first line declare that your script is an expect script and expect script uses Tcl scripting language. What you did was mixing bash and Tcl in the same script, which is why the error message. Setting up an list in Tcl and loop over is easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set arr {ip1 ip2}
foreach i $arr {
   spawn ssh myhost@$i
   send "exit\r"
}
```